# Validator will not accept null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 with C#. Visual Studio created some models based off a database I already created.  One of the columns in the database was set to non null.  I have since went back to the database and changed that column to accept null values.  However somewhere(not in the model file) it still has that column denoted as non null.  If don't enter something in the form to create a record I get the red validation error that the value cannot be null.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using EF in your project? If yes what approach did you use (code first, model first, etc)?

Comment: Yes I am using EF model first?  I connected to my database and it autogenerated a bunch of models.

Comment: in your model (the one used in the view), the Id property should be `Int?` (nullable) and no more `Int` (non nullable).

Comment: In the model used in the view the id property is type long.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because your out of date database model diagram if you have one generated.

Open database diagram file, delete all tables there (or just edit the one you need). If you are refreshing the whole diagram and deleted the current one, open Database Explorer toolbar and refresh it, select all your tables and then drag'n'drop them again to opened diagram file. At the end save it, of course.

Comment: I selected all the tables in server explorer and dragndropped them and it did nothing.

Comment: @Joe - http://i.imgur.com/7YeEQ9N.png (Don't worry it's not MVC, updating the diagram looks the same, just colour scheme may be the dark one)

Comment: I cant find any diagram in my solution, I do remember seeing that a while ago when i first connect to my database but I cant find it now.

Comment: It may be in `App_*` folder or in the main one

Comment: Its not in either of the app_* folders and i dont see it anywhere else either.  I guess ill just have to start over.